# How to Install React- Naitve project after uninstalling it from physical device

Tags: javascript, react-native, console.log

I have recently uninstalled the react native project to rebuild the project in the physical device.

```
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'ZenFone Max Pro M1 - 10' for app:debug
Installed on 1 device.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 26s
167 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 165 up-to-date
info Connecting to the development server...
info Starting the app on "C4ATAS000000"...
```

but it would not initialize the project. after showing this error.

```
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.newproject/.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.newproject/com.newproject.MainActivity} does not exist.
Done in 37.23s.
```

What should i do to install it again in the physical device.
My Gratefulness in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error that occurs sometimes, Have a try with the below commands which might help you

- Uninstall the old app
- open project and then open terminal
- cd android
- ./gradlew clean
- cd ..
- npx react-native run-android

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked after I uninstall properly with adb command